# google repo sync with warning: 'refs/heads/...' is not signed; falling back to signed release 'v2.20'. Skipped upgrade to unverified version

Tags: git, repo

When using `repo sync`, the following warning message comes up:

```
info: A new version of repo is available
repo: Updating release signing keys to keyset ver 2.3

warning: 'refs/heads/v2.20-8-g8e91248' is not signed; falling back to signed release 'v2.20'

warning: Skipped upgrade to unverified version
repo sync has finished successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this warning happens after updating the repo to the latest version:

```sh
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/.bin/repo
```

However, the `.repo/repo` folder inside the project folder is not updated to match the latest version. Therefore, the solution is to delete the `.repo/repo` folder and re-run:

```sh
repo init ... # the command you used for initializing the project
repo sync ... # the warning should be gone now
```

Answer (score 0):

just go into `.repo/repo` and do `git pull -r`
this will update the repo version